# Icon Theme not found while opening Ktorrent

Tags: kde, icons, icon-themes, ktorrent

`$ ktorrent 
Icon theme "ubuntu-mono-dark" not found.
Icon theme "Mint-X" not found.
Icon theme "elementary" not found.
Icon theme "gnome" not found.`

I am getting this error when I am trying to open ktorrent. I tried to edit the ~/.icons/index.theme but doesn't seem to work. I am using KDE desktop environment

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: These aren't actually errors but actually warnings. KTorrent should function fine it's really a cosmetic issue related to KDE libraries doing basic app initialization.

Comment: The torrents are not being downloaded and the icon next to each download (eg. download icon, pause icon etc) are not visible. It was working perfectly for the past few months. I don't know what resulted in this.

Comment: I'm pretty certain it's not the reason your torrents aren't downloading.